# Determine if device is VoLTE capable

Tags: android, lte

Can I determine if my handset is VoLTE capable or not by any API or by any other way in android. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

VoLTE is Voice Over LTE, I Believe most of the Phone which are coming now a days are VOLte supported. See your Device Specifications Features which contains LTE bands supprted and all other information, It must have info whether VolTe supported or not.
Regarding API : Need to Check i think CP based feature, so its implemented by Chipset(Need to confirm)

Answer (score 0):

The VoLTE can be SKU dependent or generic. Now a days, most of the VoLTE support is operator based and tied up with the mobile manufacture. Means for that particular operator, mobile manufacturer will support it using OTA or pre-configured IMS setup. If its enabled, on the main screen, you will see "Vo))LTE".
Another way to check is:
Go to settings -> Mobile networks -> Here you may find "VoLTE calls on SIM(enable/disable)"
Again, if VoLTE is not generic, then even if phone supports VoLTE for one operator, if you change the sim with another operator(also having VoLTE support). But, you will not see this option.

If you manage to connect to AT port, then also you can verify if you are able to add/activate secondory pdp context for IMS and verify the IMS serv state if its FULL VoIP or NO VoIP